# As a contractor - my right to substitution with IR35

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, contractor

Looking at IR 35 compliance : http://www.contracteye.co.uk/ir35_compliance_overview.shtml

> Substitution
>
> An important IR35 factor, you should ensure that your contract allows
>   you to provide a substitute in the event that you are unable to work
>   at your client site due to illness or other eventuality. The right to
>   substitution must always be a genuine one, with any costs of providing
>   the substitute met by your own company.

As a contractor to be IR35 compliant your contract must allow the provision of a substitute.

1. Does this mean if I'm off sick I would need to have someone to go in
   that day?
2. Can you have the right to provide a substitute but not follow it through?
3. Or do you negotiate it into your contract then this is something the agency that hired you deal with

I just don't see how any individual with a Limited company could be compliant with the clause. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you are a licensed plumber working solo and you have a contract with a builder to do the plumbing on a house that is being built. Your job has to be finished by a given date. If you fall ill or are unable to work for any reason, what happens? Will the builder give you an extension of time? Remember that the builder may have other subcontractors lined up to do other jobs right after your
work is completed, and so your
contract may specifically say that extensions of time are not permitted,
and that penalties will be imposed for failure to complete the work on time.
If the contract does not allow you to send in another licensed plumber to do 
the work (and pay that plumber as a sub-subcontractor out of the money you get
from the builder), then what?

Another plumber could, in most instances, replace you and do the necessary
 work if you are ill.  If you are a software developer working on
site on contract, it might be harder to get another programmer to go in
and start writing code from the point that you left off the previous
evening: the learning curve to figure out what is going on might be just
too steep.

In the US, the Internal Revenue Service has rules about
when someone that a company claims is an independent contractor (and so
the company is neither liable for various employment taxes nor required
to pay employment benefits) is actually a *contract employee* because
(among other reasons) the work conditions imposed -- come in to our 
job site, do what we tell you to do using our computers, etc -- more 
closely resemble employment than independent contracts.  It seems from
the website that you provide a link to that the UK has similar rules too.
If you don't have the right to send in someone else to do your work
at the client's site (and also satisfy various other conditions that
a truly independent contractor would satisfy), then,
in the eyes of the tax authorities,
you are effectively an employee of your client 
regardless of what you or your client or the contract between
you and the client says.

Comment: Sorry I should have said I'm talking from a software dev perspective. That doesn't really answer it as I know some IT contractors are IR35 compliant so there must be something you can do. The use of company computer is a separate IR35 clause that is a separate issue.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: As I would be employed by an agency that would pair me with the company. I suppose in the contract it would need to state that the agency would replace me, therefore satisfying the IR35 ( but in practice the company would probably just wait)?

Comment: **Employed** is the key buzzword. If you are an **employee** of the agency, you are entitled to benefits including holidays, sick leave, etc. If you are an independent contractor with the agency, then read your contract with the agency to see if you have to provide _them_ with a substitute.

Comment: Bah I'm as confused as at the start then. I can't see how any singular contractor with their own Limited company can satisfy the IR35 then.

Comment: Bah indeed. If you have a contract to supply some piece of software in six weeks' time, can work from home or your office on your own computer(s), set your own hours (work till midnight some day if need be), etc., you are an independent contractor. If you have to go to the client's site, clock in, work eight hours each day on the client's computers, are allowed to have lunch in the employee cafeteria, etc. then you are looking more and more like a contract employee.  Seems to me that you want to eat your cake and have it too.

Comment: Thats what all the other contractors in our work do! Cake cake cake. Alright thanks I'll have to go buy more lottery tickets :p

Comment: In the US, some software developers file complaints with the IRS wanting to be classified as contract employees because it is more beneficial for them, and employers try to resist this. It seems that you are in the opposite mode.  Work with the client to get a good deal.

Comment: Not that way round in the UK mate ;-)